# Count value of key in array

Tags: php, arrays, count, predicate

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [boks_1] => Array
        (
            [tittel] => Test
            [innhold] => &nbsp;    This is a test text
            [publish] => 2
        )

    [boks_2] => Array
        (
            [tittel] => Test 3
            [innhold] => This is a text test
            [publish] => 1
        )

    [boks_3] => Array
        (
            [tittel] => Kontakt oss
            [innhold] => This is a test text
            [publish] => 1
        )
)
```

How can I use PHP `count()` to count how many times `[publish] => 1` appears in my array? I am going to use the value to control the width of `divs` in a flexbox container.

Comment: You can't simply use the `count()` function, you will need to loop through the array and increment a counter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fun:

```
$count = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'publish'))[1];
```

- Get an array of the `publish` keys
- Count the values
- Get the count of the `1`s using index `[1]`

O.K. more fun:

```
$count = count(array_keys(array_column($array, 'publish'), 1));
```

- Get an array of the `publish` keys
- Get array keys where the value is `1`
- Count the array

**NOTE**: You might want to pass `true` as the third argument to `array_keys()` to be more accurate and use `'1'` instead of `1` if the `1`s are strings and not integers.

Comment: Just a question, what is the `, 1)` in `array_count_values` doing? I don't see it in the documentation as having a second parameter? That supposed to be part of the `array_column()` I think?

Comment: So `array_column($array, 'publish', 1)` instead of `array_column($array, 'publish'), 1)`?'

Comment: @Rasclatt:  That was a typo, deleted.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, but I thought I would ask incase it was some legacy thing that I didn't know about, I learn a lot from other peoples answers, like `array_column()` for instance, I normally use a loop, to accomplish the same task, so now I know better!

Comment: Added more fun since you called me back here :-)  That may have been where the `, 1)` came from earlier.

Answer (score 3):

```
$newArray = array_filter($booksArray, function($bookDet) { if($bookDet["publish"]==1) { return $bookDet; } });
$getCount = count($newArray);
```

use `array_filter`  to filter out only required array details, and get a count of it.

this could be the simplest, and performance oriented as well, as it won't loop.

Comment: you have double $ sign before newArray var, which will return 0(zero) always as count..

Comment: Nice with `array_filter()`, but `==` will return for `true` and some strings.  Maybe `function($v) { return $v['publish'] === 1; }` or if string `=== '1'`.

Answer (score 1):

this should solve your problem :

```
$array = array(); //This is your data sample

$counter = 0; //This is your counter
foreach ($array as $key => $elem) {
    if (array_key_exists('publish', $elem) && $elem['publish'] === 1) {
        $counter += $elem['publish'];
    }
}
```

hope this'll help,

Comment: went wrong with the question, OP is asking particular count of `publish==1`

Comment: yeah i forgot the condition, so i updated ;). But your solution is cleaner than mine.